# Get current Quartz.NET IJobExecutionContext FireInstanceId from service

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, quartz.net

I have this job definition for a Quartz.NET job:

```cs
public class ProcessMessageJob : IJob
{
    private readonly ILogger<ProcessMessageJob> _logger;
    private readonly TransferMessageService _transferMessageService;

    public ProcessMessageJob(ILogger<ProcessMessageJob> logger, TransferMessageService transferMessageService)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _transferMessageService = transferMessageService;
    }

    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        await _transferMessageService.ProcessTransferMessages();
    }
}
```

I want to have the `context.FireInstanceId` from the Quartz.NET job available in my service to add logging like so (**without** adding the fireinstanceId as parameter to every method call):

```cs
public async Task ProcessTransferMessages()
{
    var fireInstanceId = magicSpell.getCurrentQuartzFireInstanceId();
    _logger.LogInformation("FireinstanceId: {fireInstanceId}", fireInstanceId);
}
```

Is there anything available directly from Quartz.NET or can I solve this using dependency injection e.g. when creating a new scope in my job?

```cs
public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
    var scope = _services.CreateScope();
    var tms = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TransferMessageService>(); 
    //add FireInstanceId here somehow??
    await tms.ProcessTransferMessages();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Mind, that I use `Serilog` for logging here.*

1. Using [`LogContext.PushProperty`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment#the-logcontext) set a Serilog property with `FireInstanceId` at the start of your job's `Execute(IJobExecutionContext)`
2. Use the property in your sink's [`outputTemplate`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output)

That's it. Now, the `FireInstanceId` is logged even from your job's dependencies.

#### Example

```cs
using Serilog.Context;

class MyJob : IJob
{
    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext jobContext)
    {
        using var _ = LogContext.PushProperty("JobFireInstanceId", jobContext.FireInstanceId);

        // Job logic...
    }
}
```

```cs
outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} {Level} {JobFireInstanceId}] {Message}{NewLine}"
```

###### Logged record

```
[2023-11-13 17:02:05 Debug 638354729585261760] My log message
```

Check [the changes in my side project `QuartzSerilogPlayground`](https://github.com/foka/QuartzSerilogPlayground/commit/8b9a09376d345a2a0e9c0e627eceededdee0c73f).

#### Improvements

Now when you got it working, you may want to consider some improvements. Maybe you don't want to copy&paste such an instruction into every one of your jobs. Maybe you don't want to repeat the property name in all jobs. Maybe you want to configure the behavior once globally and not change the jobs at all.

I considered base job class with the behavior, but in the end I stayed with simple extension method on `IJobExecutionContext` so my jobs start with:

```cs
public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext jobContext)
{
    using var _ = jobContext.PushSerilogPropertyJobFireInstanceId();
```

[I've tried a global approach](https://github.com/foka/QuartzSerilogPlayground/commit/196b382f82fc10415cc651e977b33ec3ddd6a97b), without success. I wanted to declare it once for all jobs using a [job listener](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/trigger-and-job-listeners.html).

Comment: Thank you, that helped! NLog has basically the same mechanism https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v5.0.0/html/M_NLog_ScopeContext_PushProperty.htm